# What is "Spring legacy project"?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-tool-suite

The other day I was playing around with the Spring ToolSuite (STS), and noticed that project types like ("classic") Spring Framework application and Spring MVC are underneath the "Spring *legacy* project". Does it mean that it is to be phased out, or it is under a deprecation process?

[image: Spring legacy project]

Comment: A Spring based project without Spring Boot.

Comment: @M.Deinum Could you please elaborate on how a non spring-boot based project is related to being legacy project (type)?

Comment: Legacy as in not recommended/old style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@M.Deinum is absolutely correct (in the comments above). The `Spring Legacy Project` wizard helps you to create Spring projects that do not use Spring Boot, which is the recommended way to create new Spring projects. Even though using the Spring framework without Spring Boot is absolutely fine and is not deprecated by any means, we are going to remove wizards and additional extras around that in future versions of the Spring tools in order to lead newbies in the direction of Spring boot when using the Spring tools.